# How to set maximum files to select in UIDocumentPickerViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I need to set a number of files that can be selected by enabling the UIDocumentPickerViewController `allowsMultipleSelection`, but I didn't find any properties that I could use to set this.

It is possible?

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this, you'll need to implement `UIDocumentPickerDelegate`'s `didPickDocumentsAt`. It would look something like this:

```
class YourViewController: UIDocumentPickerViewController {
    let maxDocs = 3

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        delegate = self
    }
}

extension YourViewController: UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {

        // check to make sure you haven't hit your document cap specified above
        guard urls.count < maxDocs else { return }

        // if you pass the guard, business as usual
    }
}
```

I haven't worked with this class before, so there may be some rough edges, but that's the physics for poets way of how you'd do it. You may need to refine it a bit, as I'm not sure where the URLs for the delegate method come from. You could throw in a breakpoint when this method is called and do `po urls` to see what's in there.

In looking at the delegate methods available for this class, I don't see one for selecting an individual document, so you'll need to tinker around to see what happens with the array of URLs that's a parameter in the delegate method and figure out how much bookkeeping you need to do to handle state toggling between selected and !selected.

Comment: I have no idea what the rest of your code looks like, so you'll have to do some of the work on your own to determine what the URLs are, etc.

Comment: This code only works as a workaround, as it checks the selection after the user has actually selected more than 3 files.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use :

> UIDocumentBrowserViewController

instead of UIDocumentPickerViewController.  It will allow you to select multiple items :

```
   let document = UIDocumentBrowserViewController(forOpeningFilesWithContentTypes: ["public.text", "com.apple.iwork.pages.pages", "public.data"])

  func documentBrowser(_ controller: UIDocumentBrowserViewController, didPickDocumentsAt documentURLs: [URL]) {
    print("result.........\(documentURLs)")

}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    document.delegate = self
    document.allowsPickingMultipleItems = true

 }
```

And don't forget to add UIDocumentBrowserViewControllerDelegate to your VC.

Comment: ```UIDocumentBrowserViewController. allowsPickingMultipleItems``` it's the same thing as ```UIDocumentPickerViewController.allowsMultipleSelection```

Comment: Did you try the two first? I did and The document browser allowed me to select multiple items while document picker only selects one.

Comment: yes. By what documentation says is that
UIDocumentPickerViewController is supported starting with IOS 8 and
UIDocumentBrowserViewController is supported from IOS 11
but the UIDocumentPickerViewController allowsMultipleSelection property is also supported only from IOS 11